# Syntax error encountered in WebGL 2.0 GLSL when using sampler3D

Tags: javascript, firefox, glsl, webgl, webgl2

I am trying to render a 3D medical data in a brower using WebGL 2.0.

AFAIK 3D textures are now supported in WebGL 2.0.

texImage3D() is a recognized function call.

I am writing a fragment shader and declaring a uniform sampler:

```
uniform sampler3D samp;
```

When i run it on Firefox, I get an error :

> uncaught exception: Shader compile error: ERROR: 0:19: 'sampler3D' :
>    Illegal use of reserved word  ERROR: 0:19: 'sampler3D' : syntax error

Works just fine when I use sampler2D (does not solve my purpose though).

Could anybody please point me as to what am I doing wrong here?

Is sampler3D not supported yet?
But in that case how is any texture that is loaded using texImage3D() supposed to be accessed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you change all the things you need to change to use WebGL 2.0 features like `sampler3D`?

To use `sampler3D` you need to add

```
#version 300 es
```

To the top of your shader. **IT HAS TO BE THE FIRST LINE WITH NO WHITESPACE IN FRONT**

Note there are many other changes to GLSL 3.00 from GLSL 1.0

Testing here

```js
"use strict";

const vs = `#version 300 es

in vec4 position;

void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
}
`;

const fs = `#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
precision lowp sampler3D;

uniform sampler3D u_someTexture;

out vec4 theColor;

void main() {
  theColor = texture(u_someTexture, vec3(0,0,0));
}
`;

function main() {
  var m4 = twgl.m4;
  var gl = twgl.getContext(document.createElement("canvas"));
  log("using: " + gl.getParameter(gl.VERSION));  
  if (!twgl.isWebGL2(gl)) {
    log("Sorry, this example requires WebGL 2.0");  
    return;
  }

  var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs], (err) => {
    log("could not compile shader: " + err);
  });
  if (programInfo) {
    log("compiled shader with sampler3D");
  }

}
main();

function log() {
  var elem = document.createElement("pre");
  elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, " ")));
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes. The GLSL version declaration line was missing. Thank you.